# Are the events raised in a private transaction in quorum also private?

Tags: events, quorum

I'm trying to understand the specifics of privacy in quorum transactions, specially regarding the events.
Are the events raised in a private transaction in quorum also private? I can't find any specific information about this in the quorum docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Quorum, the main chain has hashes of the *encrypted transactions* that are exchanged by participants in a `privateFor` transaction. This not open to interpretation by other nodes, by design.

Events emitted by transactions are the result of nodes interpreting the transactions and any bytecode that is involved. One might say events are not broadcast per se but discovered locally.

So yes, events are private to nodes that have knowledge of both the contract and specific transactions that emit them.

Hope it helps.